# psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a table. When I try to insert an empty string into a Textfield, I am getting the `invalid input syntax for integer` error message.

Other textfields work fine with empty string.

My code:

```
cur_p.execute("""
                INSERT INTO a_recipient (created, mod, agreed, address, honor)
                VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, %s, %s)""", (None, None))
```

`psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 35: ...                  '', ''..`

The code works fine if I remove the last `current_timestamp` in the values as well as the `agreed` but if I put it back, the error message re-appears.

I checked other threads opened here in SO, I found this but the problem was about the values in array [input error: integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945824/error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-for-a-non-integer)

Any advice?

Comment: Could you add the data types of your table columns?

Comment: `created = timestamp with timezone
mod = timestamp with timezone
agreed = timestamp with timezone
address = text
honor = text`

Answer (score 1):

So there appear to be a few issues here.

First, in your `INSERT INTO` you have five columns that you name (created, mod, etc.) but in your `VALUES` statement `(%s, %s)` you only have two variables.

I don't know what the data types of your columns are but the error may be because you're trying to insert empty strings `''` into an integer field.  Try using `None` instead of the empty strings.  Psycopg2 converts Python None objects to SQL NULL.

I also don't think you need the trailing comma after "honor".

Comment: I updated my code. the "honor" column is a textfield. Tried replacing the empty string with None, still no good.

Comment: Do you get the same error? Also, the None should not be in quotes.

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus, it works! Is it advisable to put None instead of empty strings? I have like 150 textfield columns that are not nullable so i put `' '` in them instead of None.

Comment: Oh, problem sorry. When I replace the empty string with `None`, I am getting the error `honor" violates not-null constraint` cause the field is not nullable. As I workaround to other textfields that are nullable too, I put empty string `' '`

Comment: If you don't have data for the fields and you can do so making them nullable would be better than filling them with strings of `'  '`.  If the fields aren't nullable though None won't work because it is converted to NULL by psycopg2.

Comment: My backend is Django and as per the documentation, it's not advisable to put null=True 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/